# Ensure synchronous SQL query calls on a Microsoft Access database with VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a vba script that loops through several update queries performed on a table in Microsoft Access.

Should i use CurrentDb.Execute or DoCmd.RunSQL to ensure that the update queries are run sequentially and do not get ahead of each other?

Essentially,

```
Do Until Counter = 7

CurrentDb.Execute "sql_update1"
CurrentDb.Execute "sql_update2"
CurrentDb.Execute "sql_update3"

Counter = Counter + 1
Loop
```

I want to make sure that sql_update2 does not start running until sql_update1 is finished as sql_update2 relies on what sql_update1 did.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if `Execute` returned before any work it triggered was completed - that would be a terrible design...  FYI I would review the info here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-execute-method-dao   "Therefore, always use the dbFailOnError option when using the Execute method to run an update or delete query. This option generates a run-time error and rolls back all successful changes if any of the records affected are locked and can't be updated or deleted."

Comment: ...there is an option to pass `dbRunAsync` but it's not the default behavior and I'm not sure it applies in your case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .. ensure that the update queries are run sequentially

VBA is single-threaded, so it can only run the queries - and any other code - sequentially.

You will need a call to an external process to obtain something to run asynchronously. `Shell` is typically used for that.